# Binary representation of breast cancer wisconsin database

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, categorical-data

I want to produce a binary representation of the well-known breast cancer Wisconsin database.

The initial data set has 31 numerical variables, and one categorical variable.

```
 id_number diagnosis radius_mean texture_mean perimeter_mean area_mean smoothness_mean compactness_mean concavity_mean concave_points_mean symmetry_mean
1    842302         M       17.99        10.38         122.80    1001.0         0.11840          0.27760         0.3001             0.14710        0.2419
2    842517         M       20.57        17.77         132.90    1326.0         0.08474          0.07864         0.0869             0.07017        0.1812
3  84300903         M       19.69        21.25         130.00    1203.0         0.10960          0.15990         0.1974             0.12790        0.2069
4  84348301         M       11.42        20.38          77.58     386.1         0.14250          0.28390         0.2414             0.10520        0.2597
5  84358402         M       20.29        14.34         135.10    1297.0         0.10030          0.13280         0.1980             0.10430        0.1809
```

I want to produce a binary representation of this dataframe by:

transforming the diagnosis column (levels= M , B) to two columns diagnosis_M and diagnosis_B and put 1 or 0 in the relevant row depending on the value in the initial column (M or B).

Looking for the median of each numerical column and split it as two columns depending on whether the values are greater or lower than the mean value. eg: for the column radius_mean, split it in radius_mean_great in-which we put 1 if the values > mean, o else; and a column radius_mean_low inversely.

```
library(mlbench) 
library("RCurl") 
library("curl")
UCI_data_URL <- getURL('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data') 

names <- c('id_number', 'diagnosis', 'radius_mean', 'texture_mean', 'perimeter_mean', 'area_mean', 'smoothness_mean', 'compactness_mean', 'concavity_mean','concave_points_mean', 'symmetry_mean', 'fractal_dimension_mean', 'radius_se', 'texture_se', 'perimeter_se', 'area_se', 'smoothness_se', 'compactness_se', 'concavity_se', 'concave_points_se', 'symmetry_se', 'fractal_dimension_se', 'radius_worst', 'texture_worst', 'perimeter_worst', 'area_worst', 'smoothness_worst', 'compactness_worst', 'concavity_worst', 'concave_points_worst', 'symmetry_worst', 'fractal_dimension_worst') 

breast.cancer.fr <- read.table(textConnection(UCI_data_URL), sep = ',', col.names = names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are several ways to binarize the base, I found the following I hope it serves

```
df <- breast.cancer.fr[,3:32]
df2 <- matrix(NA, ncol = 2*ncol(df), nrow = nrow(df))
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
df2[,2*i-1]<- as.numeric(df[,i] >  mean(df[,i]))
df2[,2*i]  <- as.numeric(df[,i] <= mean(df[,i]))}
colnames(df2) <- c(rbind(paste0(names(df),"_great"),paste0(names(df),"_low")))

library(dplyr)
df3 <- select(breast.cancer.fr,id_number,diagnosis) %>% mutate(diagnosis_M = as.numeric(diagnosis == "M")) %>%
  mutate(diagnosis_B = as.numeric(diagnosis == "B"))

df <- cbind(df3[,-2],df2)
df[1:10,1:7]
   id_number diagnosis_M diagnosis_B radius_mean_great radius_mean_low texture_mean_great texture_mean_low
1     842302           1           0                 1               0                  0                1
2     842517           1           0                 1               0                  0                1
3   84300903           1           0                 1               0                  1                0
4   84348301           1           0                 0               1                  1                0
5   84358402           1           0                 1               0                  0                1
6     843786           1           0                 0               1                  0                1
7     844359           1           0                 1               0                  1                0
8   84458202           1           0                 0               1                  1                0
9     844981           1           0                 0               1                  1                0
10  84501001           1           0                 0               1                  1                0
```

Comment: Thanks that's great